# usecase question : can it be stand alone?

Tags: use-case

Im suppose to make a usecase diagram to a virtual school system:

Im doing well until I reached this :

> " the student sign-in the system and
>   do the entrance exam and then sign-out
>   awaiting a response. at the end of the
>   exam, **THE SYSTEM** calculates the
>   notes and according to the final note
>   **IT SET** the level for the student to inform himn with the results, the
>   date to pay the fees and the class
>   program. **THE SYSTEM** will also send
>   the student information to the schools
>   accounting system in order to
>   calculate other fees and how to pay
>   them. after paying the fees **THE
>   SYSTEM** should modify the user
>   (student) type from " student under
>   registery" to student. "

now when its saying THE SYSTEM what should i do make a stand alone use case that is not connected (associated)  with any actor ?! can i do that ?

and can anyone post links on examples , I found many but if you know a place where i can find a perfect examples please provide.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

An external system can be an actor. Just like a person interfaces with the system you're modeling, so an external system can interface with your system.

I don't like using use cases for system-to-system processes, but for the occasional interaction it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

In [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-Automation/runTestsInteractionDiagram.png) sequence diagram, the curved arrow labelled `runtests` is a system action/operation. In your case, you can have a first lane for the user (student) and a second one for the system then describe you usecase as interactions (i.e. arrows) between the two lane or cyclic arrow pointing on the system.
See also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) wikipedia page.

Comment: @RC no its not a sequence diagram , its a usecase there should be actors and usecases.

Comment: Then you need Student and 3 use cases "sign-in", "do the entrance exam" and "sign-out".

Comment: @RC mate I did so but in the text its telling (the system) calculate and send email so what should i do make a usecase standalone ? if not : with wich actor i should associate it with ?

Comment: I would use a sequence diagram (sorry) to complete the actor one. (some reading: http://alistair.cockburn.us/Use+case+fundamentals)

Comment: 8-( I did the sequence diagram but i need a usecase .

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a usecase is. The actors diagram is only one part of the usecase description, you need to describe your system with one or more activity diagram and the whole thing should be completed with some text (see cockburn link, § The use case forms). I advise you to read also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627871/the-essense-of-usecase-diagrams